# "Always on Top" not working in VLC in Windows 7

Tags: vlc-media-player

I have recently installed Windows 7 and the latest version of VLC media player. Anyhow, the "Always on Top" feature of VLC media player is not functioning.

I have a video loaded.

Comment: Works here. Windows 7 Pro x64 SP1. VLC 2.1.1. "Always on top" is only available if you load/play a video. If you just start VLC without a video loaded, the option is grayed out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It’ll do that sometimes. VLC turns the topmost flag on whenever a video is being played and off when no video is playing, and this toggling on and off sometimes malfunctions.

It is usually fixed by either manually turning it off and then on again, or restarting VLC.

Comment: Restarting does the stuff.

Comment: It just works when video is playing.

Answer (score 17):

I was searching for it and just found solution. Minimize all the windows. Then uncheck and check "always on top" then click on desktop. Then you can open all the other windows

Comment: Thank you! This one worked for me (Windows 10)

Comment: Wow, it's amazing that you got this!

Comment: this fix worked for me. BTW you can quickly minimize everything by hitting `Win+D`. D for Desktop.

Comment: Verified in 2023.... works like a charm!

Answer (score 6):

1. Close the VLC player and try running it as an Administrator (on Windows 10, search in Start Menu; right click; then select "Run as administrator")
2. Then make sure "Always on top" in the "View" menu is checked.

This worked for me.

Comment: This is right answer for me windows 10

Comment: This is the only thing that worked.

Answer (score 1):

i tried it an it seems there is conflict between "Fullscreen" and "always on top" options ,

here is how i fixed it :

1. clear the check boxes of "Fullscreen" and "always on top" options
2. save and exit VLC
3. check the box of "always on top" option 4-
4. save and exit VLC